# How to install mplayer1.1 in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, mplayer

Is there any way I can install mplayer 1.1 in my Ubuntu 13.10 ? Ubuntu repositories  are having mplayer 1.0 & They don't have Mplayer 1.1. How can I install it ?

Answer (score 2):

Download mplayer 1.1 source and compile it.

```
wget http://www.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/MPlayer-1.1.1.tar.xz
tar xvf MPlayer-1.1.1.tar.xz
cd MPlayer-1.1.1

sudo apt-get install yasm
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

if yasm already installed in your Ubuntu , then no need to install it.

thats it will install mplayer 1.1 in your Ubuntu.

hope that helps.